# scrolling text stops after opening a hyperlink

Tags: html, css, marquee

I have a marquee that works with css:

```css
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight:bold;
  height: 45px;  
}

.marquee p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  line-height: 45px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee { /* Animation marquee */
  0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
 
  <p> Here stands some Information! </p>
 
</div>


<div id="box1">test1
  <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" > text1 </a>
</div>
<div id="box2" >test2
  <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" > text2 </a></div>
<div id="box3" >test3
  <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" > text1 </a>
</div>
```

Question: I click on a hyperlink and it opens in a new tab. When I go back to my site, the marquee stops at the place where it was when the hyperlink opened! How can I refresh the scrolling text automatically, that it also scrolls after opening a hyperlink ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, off-topic: mixing german and english comments might be a bit distracting, also you have to include a procotol when linking to another page `http://www.google.de`, `www.google.de` will go to the  `current page/www.google.de`

Comment: Another thing, does the issue also come up [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/8k7rn47c/)?

Comment: @Tarekis In my original page I have hyperlinks linked to documents on a network drive and when I click on a link which opens in a new target and then go back to my original site, the marquee doesn't move, it stopped at the place where it was when I clicked on the hyperlink!

Comment: I'm sorry i cannot reproduce it by any means, tested in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/8k7rn47c/) and [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/mefinogoye/1/edit?html,css,output) on Firefox and Chrome, you either have a bug in the code you did not provide or this is a _very_ brwoser-specific bug, which i do rather not believe.

Comment: okay I will try another marquee version! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Too bad the error is not reproducable for me. And okay, then you might think a CSS approach won't work, could try a JS based option, i found two examples which seem to work perfectly fine: [1](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee) [2](https://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee)

Comment: It might be browser specific. I'm having this exact issue, but only in IE. The hover-stop doesn't work in Edge and there's no issue in Chrome!